# Order of floats and bibliography and appendix

Tags: floats, bibliographies, appendices

I am having trouble getting the order that I wish of my figures, bibliography, and appendix. I would like the order to be: body, bibliography, floats, appendix (which also includes some floats).  Currently, my floats are occurring after the appendix (I'm using the endfloat package), but I would like them before the appendix. I've tried clearpage but it doesn't work. Here is a MWE of what I currently have:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{morefloats}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[nomarkers,nolists]{endfloat}


\begin{document}

body here 

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{lc}
1&1\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

body here too

\pagebreak

\bibliography{References}

\pagebreak
\appendix
\input{appendix.tex}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put `\processdelayedfloats` just before the `appendix`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{morefloats}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[nomarkers,nolists]{endfloat}


\begin{document}

body here

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{lc}
1&1\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

body here too

\pagebreak

\bibliography{References}

\pagebreak
\processdelayedfloats   %%%<--- here
\appendix
%\input{appendix.tex}
\chapter{Appendix}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{this is a figure in appendix}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm!